# Switch view in MSDN

Tags: asp.net

I happend to visit below URL where they have implemented the different type of view of the same page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733082(classic).aspx

1. Is there any new feature in ASP.net which will allow or simplfy that kind of view ?
2. Or they have written UI rendering based on the view user selects ?

I would like to get some thoughts how they done that.

Comment: you should accept answers to your questions and vote more!

Answer (score 1):

Design your page cleverly and you can do it simply by switching CSS files.  You can see this in action here:

http://www.csszengarden.com/

Alternatively you can use asp.net [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) to define several layouts and then load them based on user selection.

```
this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/style1.master";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you take a closer look at the page you will see that the differences between the three modes: *Classic*, *Lightweight Beta*, and *Script Free* aren't entirely contained to different css style sheets.

In my experience designing a website where you can alter the layout significantly simply by switching css style sheets is far from being trivial if at all possible in some cases.

As far as ASP.NET having the ability to do that *out of the box* for any arbitrary ASP.NET Web Application project - I don't think so.

Like [@Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655634/switch-view-in-msdn/1655655#1655655) said, that requires a lot of careful planning and most likely a combination of different CSS styles, slighlty different HTML content and in some cases even different JS scripts (see the *Script Free* version of the revamped MSDN).

Of the two alternatives proposed in the question the most likely is #2. Also, don't loose sight of [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) which may provide an easier framework to work with if you're interested in creating alternative *views* for the same data. After all isn't that in a way an aspect of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)? Having the ability to have multiple pluggable views for the same data.

Comment: Good call on the MVC Miky - should have thought of that myself considering I am in the process of evaluating it for a new project :D

Answer (score 1):

More than likely what you're seeing is some kind of master page switching going on with the new MSDN site. Looking at the different sections, it appears that the same basic layouts have existed in the past, but have never been brought together under one roof. With the new design came the way to bring in these new/old layouts and combine them together.

Scott Hanselman works on the "Server and Tools Online" team at Microsoft. He has a [nice article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ANewMSDNForANewOperatingSystemAndANewDevelopmentEnvironment.aspx) about the new MSDN design and what it took to get it up and going.

Hope this helps some.